# Petrinet: How do I bring the figure to the center of the page

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment

In an `article` environment, how do I bring the `tikzpicture` to the center of the page. `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` do not work.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{squarenode/.style = {
    shape  = rectangle,
    fill   = gray!50,
    draw   = black,
    thick,
    minimum height = 1cm,
    minimum width  = 1cm
}}

\tikzset{circlenode/.style = {
    shape  = circle,
    fill   = blue!20,
    draw   = blue,
    thick,
    minimum size = 1cm
}}

\tikzset{redcirclenode/.style = {
    shape  = circle,
    fill   = red!20,
    draw   = red,
    thick,
    minimum size = 1cm
}}

\tikzset{help lines/.style=very thin}
\tikzset{My Grid/.style={help lines,color=blue!50}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [>=stealth']
  %\draw[My Grid] (-5,-5) grid (15,15);
  \node (r1) at (-4,4) [squarenode] {};
  \node[right=4cm of r1] (r2) [squarenode] {};
  \node[below=3cm of r1] (r3) [squarenode] {};
  \node[right=4cm of r3] (r4) [squarenode] {};
  \node[right=1.5cm of r1] (s2) [circlenode] {};
  \node[above=1cm of s2] (s1) [circlenode] {}; %s1
  \node[below=1cm of s2] (s3) [circlenode] {}; %s3
  \node[above=1ex of s3,red] {$s \leq 3$};
  \node[right=1.5cm of r3] (s4) [circlenode] {};
  \node[below=1cm of s4] (s5) [circlenode] {}; %s5
  \draw[fill=black] (s1.center) circle [radius=0.1cm];
  \draw[fill=black] (s5.center) circle [radius=0.1cm];
  \draw[->] (r1) -- (s2);
  \draw[->] (s2) -- (r2);
  \draw[->] (r3) -- (s4);
  \draw[->] (s4) -- (r4);
  \draw[->] (s1) to [out=180,in=90] (r1);
  \draw[->] (r1) to [out=-90,in=180] (s3);
  \draw[->] (s3) to [out=0,in=-90] (r2);
  \draw[->] (r2) to [bend right=45] node[auto,swap] {2} (s1);
  \draw[->] (r3) to [out=90,in=180] (s3);
  \draw[->] (s3) to [out=0,in=90] (r4);
  \draw[->] (r4) to [bend left=45] node[auto] {2} (s5);
  \draw[->] (s5) to [bend left=45] (r3);
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \node [fill=gray!15,rounded corners,fit=(s1) (s3) (s5) (r1) (r2)] (R1) {};
  \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}[xshift=10cm]
    \node (r1) at (-4,4) [squarenode] {};
    \node[right=4cm of r1] (r2) [squarenode] {};
    \node[below=3cm of r1] (r3) [squarenode] {};
    \node[right=4cm of r3] (r4) [squarenode] {};
    \node[right=1.5cm of r1] (s2) [circlenode] {};
    \node[above=1cm of s2] (s1) [circlenode] {}; %s1
    \node[below left=1.35cm and 0cm of s2,] (s3) [redcirclenode] {}; %s3
    \node[right=1.5cm of r3] (s4) [circlenode] {};
    \node[below=1cm of s4] (s5) [circlenode] {}; %s5
    \node[right=0.5cm of s3] (s6) [redcirclenode] {}; %s6
    \node[left=1ex of s3,red] {$s$};
    \node[right=1ex of s6,red] {$\bar{s}$};
    \draw[fill=black] (s1.center) circle [radius=0.1cm];
    \draw[fill=black] (s5.center) circle [radius=0.1cm];
    \draw[fill=black] ($(s6.center)-(0.23,0.15)$) circle [radius=0.1cm];
    \draw[fill=black] ($(s6.center)-(0,-0.23)$) circle [radius=0.1cm];
    \draw[fill=black] ($(s6.center)+(0.23,-0.15)$) circle [radius=0.1cm];
    \draw[->] (r1) -- (s2);
    \draw[->] (s2) -- (r2);
    \draw[->] (r3) -- (s4);
    \draw[->] (s4) -- (r4);
    \draw[->] (s1) to [out=180,in=90] (r1);
    \draw[->] (r1) to (s3);
    \draw[->] (s6) to (r1);
    \draw[->] (s3) to (r2);
    \draw[->] (r2) to (s6);
    \draw[->] (r2) to [bend right=45] node[auto,swap] {2} (s1);
    \draw[->] (r3) to (s3);
    \draw[->] (s6) to (r3);
    \draw[->] (s3) to (r4);
    \draw[->] (r4) to (s6);
    \draw[->] (r4) to [bend left=45] node[auto] {2} (s5);
    \draw[->] (s5) to [bend left=45] (r3);
        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
            \node [fill=gray!15,rounded corners,fit=(s1) (s3) (s5) (r1) (r2)] (R2) {};
        \end{scope}
  \end{scope}

  \draw[shorten >=1mm,-to,thick,decorate,decoration={snake,amplitude=.4mm,segment length=2mm,pre=moveto,pre length=1mm,post length=2mm}] (R1) -- (R2) node [above=1mm,midway,text width=3cm,align=center] {replacement of the \textcolor{red}{capacity} by \textcolor{red}{two places}};

\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @JouleV - can you elaborate on reset the margin

Comment: The geometry package allows you to modify the margins. `\usepackage [margin=1cm] {geometry}`

Answer (score 3):

Your graphics are too large to be centered. To see this, simply load the `showframe` package that highlights the page and its margins.

It is therefore necessary to reduce the graph!
I know two different ways to reduce it:

- with Tikz `scale=.5, transform shape`
- with the macro `\scalebox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{showframe}

\tikzset{squarenode/.style = {
    shape  = rectangle,
    fill   = gray!50,
    draw   = black,
    thick,
    minimum height = 1cm,
    minimum width  = 1cm
}}

\tikzset{circlenode/.style = {
    shape  = circle,
    fill   = blue!20,
    draw   = blue,
    thick,
    minimum size = 1cm
}}

\tikzset{redcirclenode/.style = {
    shape  = circle,
    fill   = red!20,
    draw   = red,
    thick,
    minimum size = 1cm
}}

\tikzset{help lines/.style=very thin}
\tikzset{My Grid/.style={help lines,color=blue!50}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\scalebox{.5}{
\begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=.6,transform shape]
  [>=stealth']
  %\draw[My Grid] (-5,-5) grid (15,15);
  \node (r1) at (-4,4) [squarenode] {};
  \node[right=4cm of r1] (r2) [squarenode] {};
  \node[below=3cm of r1] (r3) [squarenode] {};
  \node[right=4cm of r3] (r4) [squarenode] {};
  \node[right=1.5cm of r1] (s2) [circlenode] {};
  \node[above=1cm of s2] (s1) [circlenode] {}; %s1
  \node[below=1cm of s2] (s3) [circlenode] {}; %s3
  \node[above=1ex of s3,red] {$s \leq 3$};
  \node[right=1.5cm of r3] (s4) [circlenode] {};
  \node[below=1cm of s4] (s5) [circlenode] {}; %s5
  \draw[fill=black] (s1.center) circle [radius=0.1cm];
  \draw[fill=black] (s5.center) circle [radius=0.1cm];
  \draw[->] (r1) -- (s2);
  \draw[->] (s2) -- (r2);
  \draw[->] (r3) -- (s4);
  \draw[->] (s4) -- (r4);
  \draw[->] (s1) to [out=180,in=90] (r1);
  \draw[->] (r1) to [out=-90,in=180] (s3);
  \draw[->] (s3) to [out=0,in=-90] (r2);
  \draw[->] (r2) to [bend right=45] node[auto,swap] {2} (s1);
  \draw[->] (r3) to [out=90,in=180] (s3);
  \draw[->] (s3) to [out=0,in=90] (r4);
  \draw[->] (r4) to [bend left=45] node[auto] {2} (s5);
  \draw[->] (s5) to [bend left=45] (r3);
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \node [fill=gray!15,rounded corners,fit=(s1) (s3) (s5) (r1) (r2)] (R1) {};
  \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}[xshift=10cm]
    \node (r1) at (-4,4) [squarenode] {};
    \node[right=4cm of r1] (r2) [squarenode] {};
    \node[below=3cm of r1] (r3) [squarenode] {};
    \node[right=4cm of r3] (r4) [squarenode] {};
    \node[right=1.5cm of r1] (s2) [circlenode] {};
    \node[above=1cm of s2] (s1) [circlenode] {}; %s1
    \node[below left=1.35cm and 0cm of s2,] (s3) [redcirclenode] {}; %s3
    \node[right=1.5cm of r3] (s4) [circlenode] {};
    \node[below=1cm of s4] (s5) [circlenode] {}; %s5
    \node[right=0.5cm of s3] (s6) [redcirclenode] {}; %s6
    \node[left=1ex of s3,red] {$s$};
    \node[right=1ex of s6,red] {$\bar{s}$};
    \draw[fill=black] (s1.center) circle [radius=0.1cm];
    \draw[fill=black] (s5.center) circle [radius=0.1cm];
    \draw[fill=black] ($(s6.center)-(0.23,0.15)$) circle [radius=0.1cm];
    \draw[fill=black] ($(s6.center)-(0,-0.23)$) circle [radius=0.1cm];
    \draw[fill=black] ($(s6.center)+(0.23,-0.15)$) circle [radius=0.1cm];
    \draw[->] (r1) -- (s2);
    \draw[->] (s2) -- (r2);
    \draw[->] (r3) -- (s4);
    \draw[->] (s4) -- (r4);
    \draw[->] (s1) to [out=180,in=90] (r1);
    \draw[->] (r1) to (s3);
    \draw[->] (s6) to (r1);
    \draw[->] (s3) to (r2);
    \draw[->] (r2) to (s6);
    \draw[->] (r2) to [bend right=45] node[auto,swap] {2} (s1);
    \draw[->] (r3) to (s3);
    \draw[->] (s6) to (r3);
    \draw[->] (s3) to (r4);
    \draw[->] (r4) to (s6);
    \draw[->] (r4) to [bend left=45] node[auto] {2} (s5);
    \draw[->] (s5) to [bend left=45] (r3);
        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
            \node [fill=gray!15,rounded corners,fit=(s1) (s3) (s5) (r1) (r2)] (R2) {};
        \end{scope}
  \end{scope}

  \draw[shorten >=1mm,-to,thick,decorate,decoration={snake,amplitude=.4mm,segment length=2mm,pre=moveto,pre length=1mm,post length=2mm}] (R1) -- (R2) node [above=1mm,midway,text width=3cm,align=center] {replacement of the \textcolor{red}{capacity} by \textcolor{red}{two places}};

\end{tikzpicture} 
} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I understand the key `scale`. What is the purpose of `transform shape` in Tikz

Comment: By default, enlargements and reductions do not affect the `nodes`, they only affect the `coordinates`. However, your graph is built with `nodes`, `transform shape` also allows you to make `scale` **act** on the `nodes`.

Answer (score 2):

You might just use an `adjustbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{squarenode/.style = {
    shape  = rectangle,
    fill   = gray!50,
    draw   = black,
    thick,
    minimum height = 1cm,
    minimum width  = 1cm
}}

\tikzset{circlenode/.style = {
    shape  = circle,
    fill   = blue!20,
    draw   = blue,
    thick,
    minimum size = 1cm
}}

\tikzset{redcirclenode/.style = {
    shape  = circle,
    fill   = red!20,
    draw   = red,
    thick,
    minimum size = 1cm
}}

\tikzset{help lines/.style=very thin}
\tikzset{My Grid/.style={help lines,color=blue!50}}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\adjustbox{width=\textwidth}{\begin{tikzpicture}
  [>=stealth']
  %\draw[My Grid] (-5,-5) grid (15,15);
  \node (r1) at (-4,4) [squarenode] {};
  \node[right=4cm of r1] (r2) [squarenode] {};
  \node[below=3cm of r1] (r3) [squarenode] {};
  \node[right=4cm of r3] (r4) [squarenode] {};
  \node[right=1.5cm of r1] (s2) [circlenode] {};
  \node[above=1cm of s2] (s1) [circlenode] {}; %s1
  \node[below=1cm of s2] (s3) [circlenode] {}; %s3
  \node[above=1ex of s3,red] {$s \leq 3$};
  \node[right=1.5cm of r3] (s4) [circlenode] {};
  \node[below=1cm of s4] (s5) [circlenode] {}; %s5
  \draw[fill=black] (s1.center) circle [radius=0.1cm];
  \draw[fill=black] (s5.center) circle [radius=0.1cm];
  \draw[->] (r1) -- (s2);
  \draw[->] (s2) -- (r2);
  \draw[->] (r3) -- (s4);
  \draw[->] (s4) -- (r4);
  \draw[->] (s1) to [out=180,in=90] (r1);
  \draw[->] (r1) to [out=-90,in=180] (s3);
  \draw[->] (s3) to [out=0,in=-90] (r2);
  \draw[->] (r2) to [bend right=45] node[auto,swap] {2} (s1);
  \draw[->] (r3) to [out=90,in=180] (s3);
  \draw[->] (s3) to [out=0,in=90] (r4);
  \draw[->] (r4) to [bend left=45] node[auto] {2} (s5);
  \draw[->] (s5) to [bend left=45] (r3);
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \node [fill=gray!15,rounded corners,fit=(s1) (s3) (s5) (r1) (r2)] (R1) {};
  \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}[xshift=10cm]
    \node (r1) at (-4,4) [squarenode] {};
    \node[right=4cm of r1] (r2) [squarenode] {};
    \node[below=3cm of r1] (r3) [squarenode] {};
    \node[right=4cm of r3] (r4) [squarenode] {};
    \node[right=1.5cm of r1] (s2) [circlenode] {};
    \node[above=1cm of s2] (s1) [circlenode] {}; %s1
    \node[below left=1.35cm and 0cm of s2,] (s3) [redcirclenode] {}; %s3
    \node[right=1.5cm of r3] (s4) [circlenode] {};
    \node[below=1cm of s4] (s5) [circlenode] {}; %s5
    \node[right=0.5cm of s3] (s6) [redcirclenode] {}; %s6
    \node[left=1ex of s3,red] {$s$};
    \node[right=1ex of s6,red] {$\bar{s}$};
    \draw[fill=black] (s1.center) circle [radius=0.1cm];
    \draw[fill=black] (s5.center) circle [radius=0.1cm];
    \draw[fill=black] ($(s6.center)-(0.23,0.15)$) circle [radius=0.1cm];
    \draw[fill=black] ($(s6.center)-(0,-0.23)$) circle [radius=0.1cm];
    \draw[fill=black] ($(s6.center)+(0.23,-0.15)$) circle [radius=0.1cm];
    \draw[->] (r1) -- (s2);
    \draw[->] (s2) -- (r2);
    \draw[->] (r3) -- (s4);
    \draw[->] (s4) -- (r4);
    \draw[->] (s1) to [out=180,in=90] (r1);
    \draw[->] (r1) to (s3);
    \draw[->] (s6) to (r1);
    \draw[->] (s3) to (r2);
    \draw[->] (r2) to (s6);
    \draw[->] (r2) to [bend right=45] node[auto,swap] {2} (s1);
    \draw[->] (r3) to (s3);
    \draw[->] (s6) to (r3);
    \draw[->] (s3) to (r4);
    \draw[->] (r4) to (s6);
    \draw[->] (r4) to [bend left=45] node[auto] {2} (s5);
    \draw[->] (s5) to [bend left=45] (r3);
        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
            \node [fill=gray!15,rounded corners,fit=(s1) (s3) (s5) (r1) (r2)] (R2) {};
        \end{scope}
  \end{scope}

  \draw[shorten >=1mm,-to,thick,decorate,decoration={snake,amplitude=.4mm,segment length=2mm,pre=moveto,pre length=1mm,post length=2mm}] (R1) -- (R2) node [above=1mm,midway,text width=3cm,align=center] {replacement of the \textcolor{red}{capacity} by \textcolor{red}{two places}};

\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```